# angular: maintain different representations of a collection/model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I have a factory `Expense` that encapsulates logic of presenting a list of expenses. e.g, I may need a comprehensive list, list of expenses that occurred this month, only income expenses, or even representation in a *flotcharts* format.

In `Expense` factory I have an exposed `list` property, to which I add new objects in the controller. I also have `incomes()` function that filters the `list` array for records with positive values.

The question is how should I use the `$scope` to correctly enable data-binding for all the representations.

What works for me is having `$scope.incomes = Expense.incomes` in controller (where `Expense.incomes` is a filtering **function** returning an array), and `ng-repeat="income in incomes()"` in the view. Is this a correct approach? Or maybe I should have `$scope.incomes` as an array, rather than a function, and manually update it in controller when underlying `list` updates? With a function approach, I cannot set `incomes` as a value for `ng-model`, which I want to do for my plotting directive.

Comment: for filtering the best is to use a filter. And if you have an array and assign it to `$scope.array = Expense.array;` if you modify that list in different place it will be reflecting in template. So it my opinion best option is to use `ng-repeat="item in list | Income"`.

Comment: Thanks, I also thought in that direction! But filters will be available globally, which I don't want ( only expenses can be filtered by income!), but I can live with that.
But with filters I cannot get my directive working: I used to set ng-model on DOM element, and add $scope.watch on that model, but I cannot set as a model a filtered value, right? What I want is basically <chart ng-__source__="expenses | presentAsChart">, to have access to that values in the directive, but I'm not sure how to achieve that.

If that's not clear, I can update the question with more information

Comment: jcubic: I posted a new question addressing this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352802/angular-watch-for-filtered-value-in-directive.