# angular: watch for filtered value in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to implement a directive that draws a chart based on given values.
I want the pass the data for the plot from the template.
I have a working solution, passing the data in `ng-model`, for which I can then add a `$scope.watch` statement. But that doesn't work with filtered data, and I don't need two-way binding.

Ideally, the html should look like:

```
 <chart ???????="list | filter" />
```

The directive, I guess, should look like:

```
  return{
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
        var chart = null

        scope.$watch(????, function(v){
             if(!chart){
                chart = $.plot(elem, v , options);
                elem.show();
            }else{
                chart.setData(v);
                chart.setupGrid(); 
                chart.draw();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Is there an angular way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about saving the filtered list in a different variable in your controller?
something like:

```
$scope.filteredList = $filter('yourFilter')($scope.list);
```

and in the HTML:

```
<chart ????="filteredList" />
```

You only need to make sure you update `filteredList` whenever `list` changes.

Comment: Thanks,
So I have to manually update that `filteredList`? Can it be done via angular's native binding?

Comment: You can add a `$watch` to your scope for `list`, and re-calculate `filteredList` whenever it changes.

Answer (score 1):

What about actually placing binding on the `????` variable:

```
<chart ???????="{{list | filter}}" />
```

You might also want to add in your directive:

```
  return{
    restrict: 'C',
    scope: {
        ????: "@",
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
        var chart = null

        scope.$watch(????, function(v){
             if(!chart){
                chart = $.plot(elem, v , options);
                elem.show();
            }else{
                chart.setData(v);
                chart.setupGrid(); 
                chart.draw();
            }
        });
    }
};
```